# How to assign an element of list1 with that in list2 and replace it with te assigned element of list2?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists as follows:

```
List1 = ["Steel", "ReinfSteel", "Concrete", "Wood", "Aluminium"]

List2 = ["CONCDC", "CONCR", "SOLROC", "REINFO", "STEEDC", "MCSTEL", "COMPOS", "INTERF", "MASSEL", "SPRING", "FLUSTR", "COMSRF"]
```

I want to match the data in `List1` with that in `List2` as follows:

1. Steel = MCSTEL
2. ReinfSteel = REINFO ... & so on ...

I have to write a code in python which would do as described below:
If `List1` consists of `STEEL` then replace it with `MCSTEL` in `List2` and return the new replaced (i.e `MCSTEL` in this case) in a a new variable.

I am pretty novice to Python and still learning so please excuse me if this question is too basic to ask here.

So I am trying to import a data from JSON file from one software to Python script of the other software. The data is similar but ha different syntax so I have to map the data from JSON code to Python. I have used the below code to try doing it for a single material but I need a code that would be helpful to cover all the materials given in List2:

```
KMaterial = []
for materialfamily in data['Model']['elems']:
    KMaterial.append( materialfamily['grass_element_']['crosec_']['material_' ['family_'] )
print(KMaterial)
DMaterial  = ["CONCDC", "CONCR", "SOLROC", "REINFO", "STEEDC", "MCSTEL", "COMPOS", "INTERF", "MASSEL", "SPRING", "FLUSTR", "COMSRF"]
d = {"Steel": "MCSTEL", "ReinfSteel": "REINFO", "Concrete": ""}
new_list = [d[i] if i in d else i for i in KMaterial]
print(new_list)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried out any code. If not, you should try and post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to Python, I am not trying to complicate the answer.

To get you started with some of the basics, here's a way to look at the solution.

You can use a if statement to check for each value you want. Then replace the value with the new value.

```
#you want to iterate through list1 and for each value in list1,
#you want to check if it meets your criteria
#since you need the index and value, use enumerate
for i,val in enumerate(list1):
    #if value is 'steel' you want to replace with 'MCSTEL'
    if list1[i].lower() == 'steel':
        list1[i] = 'MCSTEL'

print (list1)
```

If there are more than one item to replace, then you can have multiple if statements.

```
#you want to iterate through list1 and for each value in list1,
#you want to check if it meets your criteria
#since you need the index and value, use enumerate

for i,val in enumerate(list1):
    #if value is 'Steel' you want to replace with 'MCSTEL'
    if val.lower() == 'steel':
        list1[i] = 'MCSTEL'

    #if value is 'ReinfSteel' you want to replace with 'REINFO'
    if val.lower() == 'reinfsteel':
        list1[i] = 'REINFO'
```

If you are familiar with dictionary, you can use a dictionary to iterate through the list.

First you need to define the dictionary.  Then iterate through the list to replace each element that matches the key in the dictionary with the value from dictionary.

```
#define your dictionary with key value pairs
#key is the value you want to search in list1
#value is the new value you want to store
d = {'steel':'MCSTEL','reinfsteel':'REINFO'}

#you want to iterate through list1 and for each value in list1,
#you want to check if it meets your criteria
#since you need the index and value, use enumerate

for i,val in enumerate(list1):
    #check against the keys in the dictionary
    if val.lower() in d.keys():
        list1[i] = d[val.lower()]
```

If you understand list comprehension in python, then you can write the above loop in just one statement as:

```
list2 = [d[x.lower()] if x.lower() in d.keys() else x for x in list1]
```

Either of the code will replace:

```
['Steel', 'ReinfSteel', 'Concrete', 'Wood', 'Aluminium']
```

to

```
['MCSTEL', 'REINFO', 'Concrete', 'Wood', 'Aluminium']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dict` of key, value pairs for what you would want to swap, and then use list comprehension to create the new list. Below is an example that only has steel in it.

```
d = {"Steel": "MCSTEL"}
new_list = [d[i] if i in d else i for i in List1]
```

If you want to include something else, such as "Concrete" and "CONCR", you would include the key, value pairs `"Concrete": "CONCR"` in your dictionary `d`.